# What typeface/fonts are working with international languages on Android?

Tags: android, utf-8, fonts, font-face, typeface

I'm not sure how or where to ask this question, but I guess lots of experienced android developers here could point me in the correct direction.

What I would like is to give my users to customize their type of font/typeface. But, as the application got users from all around the world, with all kind of languages and charsets, I don't know what typefaces/fonts that supports this. I need fonts that support chinese, english/latin, cryllic, russian, arabic, etc etc... For now, I only use the default font on android, as Im not sure if any other fonts supports all these international characters. (I use utf8)

Anyone got some tips ?

Comment: I have the same question. May I know your answer?

Comment: Well, I'm still wondering... hopefully someone can contribute with a tip soon :-)